# using phia testInteraction for post-hoc interaction effect analysis with glmer mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, post-hoc, lme4-nlme

I have the following glmer mixed model:

```
model <- glmer(eggs ~ temp*diet + (1|site), family="poisson")
```

where 'eggs' is count data on the number of eggs, 'temp' is a three-level factor, 'diet' is a two-level factor, and 'site' is a random factor to account for collecting various data from multiple different sites.

I used library(phia) and:

```
testInteractions(model)
```

which gave:

```
Chisq Test: 
P-value adjustment method: holm
                Value Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
C-H : 1-2 1.15715  1 4.2718    0.07750 .
C-M : 1-2 0.94127  1 0.8626    0.35300  
H-M : 1-2 0.81344  1 8.5682    0.01026 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I interpreted this as meaning that the difference between hot (H) and medium (M) temperature factor levels was significantly different across diets 1 and 2.

However, when I add a fixed factor into the model like this:

```
model2 <- glmer(eggs ~ temp*diet + month + (1|site), family="poisson")
testInteractions(model2)
```

gives the following error:

```
 Error in testInteractions(model) : 
   Error in solve.default(L %*% V %*% t(L)) : 
   Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
```

I am new to the phia package so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here. I want to use it to test pairwise differences in number of eggs between the 3 temperature levels across the two diet levels, in order to pick apart the temp*diet interaction. I want month included in the model, but I don't want to include it in the post-hoc comparisons.

If anyone has any thoughts on how I'm using phia, and how I am interpreting the results, and about what has gone wrong in the final error message, then I would really appreciate your help.